# Set default POCO property Value from DB.Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm having a POCO class where i have a specific property (called: is_confirmed) not mapped to the database. Instead I want this property to check in another table if any is_confirmed value is true for the specific user.
I have tried by using the below code, but it gives error: `is_confirmed = The function evaluation requires all threads to run.`

My question has 2 parts:

1. How i pass the current user alias
2. How i make it work, since now it is not producing a value but an error

Here is my code so far.

```
   [Table("participants")]
    public class participant
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public string alias { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Boolean is_confirmed
        {
            get
            {
                dbContext DB;
                DB = new dbContext();
                return DB.confirmedParticipants.Where(x => x.is_confirmed == true && x.participantAlias == "aliashere").ToList().Count > 0;
            }
            set {  }
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Try encapsulate dbContext in a using statement: `using (var db = new dbContext()) {  return db.confirmedParticipants...; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally something like this wouldn't be a concern of an entity, but rather a concern for the consumer of an entity, such as a ViewModel. A Participant entity would either have the details or relationship available to assess whether it is confirmed or not. It seems unusual that a confirmation would be linked to a participant by an Alias rather than Participant ID.

Without knowing more about the table structure, given just the details that you have exposed:

```
[Table("participants")]
public class participant
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Confirmations")]
    public string alias { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ParticipantConfirmations> Confirmations { get; set; } = new List<ParticipantConfirmation>();
}
[Table("confirmedParticipants")]
public class ParticipantConfirmation
{
    [Key]
    public string alias { get; set; }
    public bool is_confirmed { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

Then when reading a view model for Participant:

```
[Serializable]
public class ParticipantViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
}
```

a typical Select:

```
var participantVMs = db.Participants.Where(x => /* some condition */)
    .Select(x => new ParticipantViewModel
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        FullName = x.firstname + " " + x.lastname,
        Alias = x.alias,
        IsConfirmed = x.Confirmations.Any(c => c.is_confirmed)
     }).ToList();
```

A key point about EF...

Avoid stuff like this:

```
.Where(x => x.is_confirmed == true && x.participantAlias == "aliashere").ToList().Count > 0;
```

Instead, use:

```
.Any(x => x.is_confirmed && x.participantAlias == "aliashere");
```

The first statement will effectively do a `SELECT * FROM [Participant_Confirmed] WHERE is_confirmed = true AND participant_alias = 'aliashere'` which will return all fields for all matching rows simply so you can check to see if a row exists.

The second statement will effectively do a `SELECT EXISTS ...` which will return a True or False result which is a faster query using less memory, and sending far less data over the wire.

On a hunch from the naming and fields, it would appear that the confirmed participants would be a view of participants flattening out whether the participant is confirmed or not. If that were the case I would simply leverage an entity bound to that view for the read operation, then load Participant if/when I wanted to update data about the participant. It's difficult to determine without seeing the whole picture but I suspect there are some considerable optimizations you can leverage to avoid going to the DB too frequently.